# getting error while converting target framework of an asp.net web application from 2.0 to 3.5

Tags: visual-studio, frameworks, target

While converting the taget framework of an asp.net web application from 2.0 to 3.5 in visual studio 2008, i am getting the error : Exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' was thrown

Comment: Same problem while converting to .Net 4.7.2 in Visual Studio 2022. Microsoft will never fix this bug.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the issue, my web application didn't have a web.config.I added a deafult web.config and then converted it.It worked fine.

Comment: +1 thanks! The web.config in my project was a linked file to a web.config in another project, and the other project had already been updated from 4.5 to 4.6. I deleted the linked file, then updated the target framework. VS auto-generated a new web.config, which I deleted, then re-added the linked reference.

Answer (score 1):

I recently upgraded the target framework in the my web project's (Asp.NET web forms) properties from 4.8 to 4.8.1.
I searched the web.config for any "targetFramework" where it was referencing older versions and changed them to "4.8.1".  Save.  Recompile.

Answer (score 0):

This may be too old, but what worked for me was to convert the Web project to the new framework first.